# Creating a user failed. Is there a way to interogate the error?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using the ASP.NET Identity framework, with the EntityFramework provider (`IdentityDbContext`).

I attempt to create a user by calling `UserManager.CreateAsync(..)`.

It returns an object of type `IdentityResult`, with the following values:

```
{
   Succeeded: false,
   Errors: ["Name AndrewShepherd is already taken."]
}
```

The error is valid - there is indeed another user called "AndrewShepherd" in the database. This is not a name the user picked; instead I am generating this name from the Outh2 account information provided by their Google account. (Google Accounts don't enforce unique names, just unique email addresses).

Since the problem is a duplicate name, I can simply try appending a number to the name and trying again. I would programmatically attempt to create AndrewShepherd_1, AndrewShepherd_2, AndrewShepherd_3 until I am either successful or get a different error.

But how do I programatically determine that the problem was a duplicate name?

Options are:

- Perform a pattern match on the error string. This solution is guaranteed to break when the next version of ASP.NET Identity has a differently worded error messages or we internationalize the website.
- Run the check before creating the user. I would call `UserStore.FindByNameAsync` to determine if the name had already been taken before invoking `UserManager.CreateASync(..)`. This would have a small concurrency  risk if two different sessions are attempting to add the same user name at the same time.

It would be some much easier if we could simply perform a check like this:

```
if(identityResult.Errors.Where(e => e.ErrorCode == IdentityErrors.DuplicateName).Any())
```

Is there a way I can perform a unique user check then add a user, that's safe in a concurrent environment?

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: @kkakkurt - yes I am. Thanks, I'll add that point to my question.

Comment: You may find this topic [Multitenancy](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy) from Scott Braddy Helpful...

Comment: @AndrewShepherd same concurrency problem can occur when `CreateAsync` calls `FindByNameAsync`, so the second option is much better

Answer (score 0):

As an alternaive, you can check if the user name is exist in your DB like that. If user name is already taken, you can change new user name like AndrewShepherd_1, AndrewShepherd_2, AndrewShepherd_3.

```
using (YourProjectName.Models.DefaultConnection db = new Models.DefaultConnection ())
        {
            if (db.AspNetUsers.Select(q => q.UserName).Contains("usernameThatYouWantToCheck"))
            {
                /*Your code*/
            }
        }
```